# Как использовать then в данной ситуации?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, cheerio

Паршу сайт, есть функция. Как мне вернуть из этой функции значение? Как я понимаю нужно сделать после `each` `then`, который будет возвращать `resolve`, но я получал ошибку `TypeError: $(...).each(...).then is not a function`, когда пытался так сделать

```js
function parse(body) {
return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
 var $ = cheerio.load(body)
 $('span').each(function(i, elem) {
    axios.get(url)
      .then(function(response) {
        // действия с полученным html
      })
      .then(function(mark) {
        // еще действия
      })
  }).then(function(data)
    return resolve(data)
 })
})
}
```

Comment: у вас так не будет работать)

Comment: и что за `cheerio`?

Comment: а зачем axios в промис если можно сам axios await и уже потом с коллекцией работать

Answer (score 1):

У вас сейчас какая ситуация: вы проходите по всем элементам, запускаете какой-то сетевой запрос и все. 
Во первых, вы ничего никуда не возвращаете, во вторых `$.each` вернет объект, где нет метода `then`.

`Jquery (cheerio)` давно не пользовался, поэтому будет смешанный ответ.

```
  function parse(body) {
    const $ = cheerio.load(body);
    // В promises массив ожиданий
    const promises = $('span').map((i, elem) => {
      return axios.get(url)
        .then(function(response) {
          // действия с полученным html
        })
        .then(function(mark) {
          // еще действия
          // тут надо что-то будет вернуть
        });
    });

    // Дождется, когда все ожидания выполнятся
    return Promise.all(promises);
  }
```

#### Полезные ссылки:

[Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all)

Comment: promise.all  и так возвращает promise,  поэтому нет смысла все еще в конструктор заворачивать

Comment: TypeError: [object Object] is not iterable

Comment: вам нужно писать так `parse(body).then(data => {});`